# Best practices to run Snakemake without enough memory

Tags: memory, snakemake, sequential

I'd like to run my snakemake pipeline on approximatively ~300 files. Unfortunately, it requires too much memory than my system actually has. So I'd like to know if there is a kind of settings, or good practices, allowing me to launch my snakemake pipeline on one file at a time (sequentially), automatically, instead of launching manually my snakemake on one file at a time.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: This question might help, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48542333/snakemake-memory-limiting

Comment: Is snakemake launching too many jobs at once for your system, or is it running out of memory before it can launch any jobs?

Comment: Marmaduke, Snakemake is actually lauching too many jobs at a time, consequently, it ends up saturating the memory. That's why I would like to launch one batch of jobs -> waiting for the batch finish running -> once the batch is over, start the second one, etc.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to lower down the number of jobs that run at the same time is the `-j` argument of snakemake. If you specify `-j 1`, you're workflow will be not be parallelized at all. Only one job will run at the same time.

However, most of the time, the amount of memory that is consumed is quite low for most of the jobs except for one or two. So what you want, is to lower the number of such jobs that run at the same time and let the other jobs be parallelized. You can achieve this with the `resources` tag in your rules.

**Example:**
In my RNAseq workflow, the aligner STAR consumes a lot of memory. Therefore I limit the number of STAR jobs to 3 at the same time.

```
rule star_PE:
    input:
            R1="{sampleName}_R1.fastq.gz",
            R2="{sampleName}_R2.fastq.gz",
            genome=GENOMEDIR+"/Genome"
    output: "{sampleName}.Aligned.sortedByCoord.out.bam"
    params: cpu=10,
            outprefix="{sampleName}."
    resources: parallel_star=1
    shell:  """
            STAR --runThreadN {params.cpu} --genomeDir {GENOMEDIR} --readFilesCommand zcat --outFileNamePrefix {params.outprefix} --readFilesIn {input.R1} {input.R2} --outSAMtype BAM SortedByCoordinate
            """
```

and I run my snakemake as follow:

```
snakemake -j 30 -rp --resources parallel_star=3
```

The `resources` tag in my rule tells snakemake that this rule will consume `1` of the `parallel_star` resource and I give snakemake a total of `3` of this resource on the command line.

To conclude, my snakemake will be able to run 30 jobs but no more that 3 `star_PE` rules at the same time.